# How to loop for a variable amount in verilog?

Tags: verilog, fpga

In any hardware definition language, I know we can't declare a loop to loop over some circuits for some variable n times, instead we need to loop for a fixed value.

So I wanted to ask, if I have the following snippets of code:
I'm writing some sort of pseudocode in verilog, and this is an unfinished code.

```
    input [7-1:0] note_switch;
    reg[7-1:0] varnum[7-1:0];
    reg[7-1:0] limit;

    wire[7-1:0] numofhigh_switch;

    check_high test (numofhigh_switch, note_switch);

    always@(posedge octave) begin
        if(octave) begin
           for(count = 0; count < numofhigh_switch; count = count + 1) begin
                varnum[numofhigh_switch + count] <= varnum[count] << 7;
            end
        end else begin
           for(count = 0; count < numofhigh_switch; count = count + 1) begin
                varnum[numofhigh_switch + count] <= varnum[numofhigh_switch + count];
            end
        end
    end
```

I wanted to make something resembling like this, but again I know this will not work in a hardware description language, so how should I write so I can get the effect of rolling the for loop?

Answer (score 1):

Actually, synthesis tools need to statically determine the *maximum* possible number of loops, not just a fixed number. You can do this a number of ways

- Put the maximum into the conditional expression

```
 for(count = 0; count < numofhigh_switch && count < 8; count = count + 1) begin
                varnum[numofhigh_switch + count] <= varnum[count] << 7;
            end
```

- Use a conditional branching statement inside the loop

```
 for(count = 0; count < 8; count = count + 1) 
   if (count < numofhigh_switch) begin
                varnum[numofhigh_switch + count] <= varnum[count] << 7;
            end
```

- In SystemVerilog you can use a `break` statement.

```
 for(count = 0; count < 8; count = count + 1) begin
                if (count >= numofhigh_switch) break;
                varnum[numofhigh_switch + count] <= varnum[count] << 7;
            end
```